# PHP Variable and MySQL Querying

Tags: php, mysql, variables

Wasn't sure what exactly to search for so apologies if this has been covered elsewhere..

Basically I have Bulkhead1, Bulkhead2, Bulkhead3 etc and I'm trying to save space by adding 1 each time but I'm going wrong somewhere! :(

Something is going wrong here - $row['Bulkhead"'.$it.'"']

```
$i=1;
while($x= mysqli_fetch_array($y)) { 
$bh = $row['Bulkhead"'.$it.'"'];
}
$i++;
```

Comment: shouldnt it be 
`while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($)) {
$bh = $row['Bulkhead"'.$it.'"'];
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try;
$bh = $row['Bulkhead'.$i];

Comment: Thanks!!  Been doing my head in!!  Probably something I would've solved if it wasn't late afternoon on a Friday.  For some reason I didn't think you could go outside the ' '..  Anyway - Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the double quotes are misused, also you are using $i and $it, is it a typo?

```
$i=1;
while($x= mysqli_fetch_array($y)) { 
    $bh = $row["Bulkhead$i"];
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want but I will try to fix your code:

```
    $i=1;
    while($x= mysqli_fetch_array($y))
    { 
   echo 'Bulkhead'. $i;
   $i++;
    }
```

Or as an array:

```
$bh  = array ();
$i=1;
while($x= mysqli_fetch_array($y))
{ 
   $ bh[ ]= 'Bulkhead'. $i;
   $i++;
}
```

If I get you wrong, try to explain your question better.